# Excel formula - find if any date in a given range matches a given year

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table listing work anniversaries, looking something like:

```
 5 years   | 10 years  | 15 years  | 20 years... etc
 27/1/2011 | 27/1/2016 | 27/1/2021 | 27/1/2026.. etc
```

I would like to check if any of the dates falls within the current year.  I can do it easily enough with a formula such as `=OR(year(cell1)=2021,year(cell2)=2021.. etc` but it's not particularly elegant.  What would be a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:F2,">="&DATE(2021,1,1),A2:F2,"<"&DATE(2022,1,1))>0
```

`A2:F2` being the dates to test

Comment: for any current year replace 2021 with `YEAR(TODAY())` and 2022 with `YEAR(TODAY())+1`.  Admittedly it will make it a volatile formula which just means it recalculates anytime anything in the worksheet changes.  Alternatively you could point 2021 at a cell containing todays date or year and work work out the needed years as required.  Or am I off my rocker Scott?

Comment: No, there is some debate whether putting `=TODAY()` in a single cell and then refering to it offsets the many recalcs or because it is dependent on that cell and that cell will recalc, will the dependencies also recalc.  Best would be to just put the year desired `2021` in a cell and then refer back to that for the year.